# android studio : log cat displays different package name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Previously I had this package in my project: `com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample`
Then I changed my project name from `navigationdrawerexample` to `mtesapp`.

Now, everywhere I am using `com.example.android.mtes`. But, In my logcat still I can see old package name. When I run the app. I am getting this error:

```
01-13 13:58:07.704  12924-12924/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample, PID: 12924
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.mtesapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

As you can see `com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.mtesapp.MainActivity`. I just need `mtes` package.

**Manifest File**

```
<permission android:name="com.example.android.mtesapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.mtesapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**EDIT**

When I start the app. It starts with:

```
01-13 14:14:44.238  13998-13998/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample I/Adreno-EGL﹕
```

Here, it should be `com.example.android.mtesapp`

Comment: In permission names still you are using `mtesapp` instead of `mtes`

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. it's mtesapp

Comment: what is package name in Manifest ?

Comment: `com.example.android.mtesapp`

Comment: try after restarting IDE and also unistall app from device if previously installed

Comment: I tried it already. I don't understand what's going on here?

Comment: @RonakPatel did you solvd that??i am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you just rename the files, or did you go through and rename them with the refactoring options to make sure they are all changed together? In Android Studio, you can right click on your package, and refactor -> rename. The shortcut key is Shift F6.

Answer (score 0):

What about the gradle files?

The packageName in manifest get's overwritten by the applicationId in the apps gradle file.

Make sure you use the new packageName also in your gradle file.